# How to access a mock object in another mock object in Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Say I have an interface that has as property another interface. Something like:

```
interface IOne  
{  
    ITwo Two { get; set;}   
}
```

And I create a mock for `ITwo` and then create a mock for `IOne` using `Mock<ITwo>.Object`. How can I raise an event on `ITwo` when I only have a reference to `IOne` or `Mock<IOne>`? I need a reference for `Mock<ITwo>`, but how can I cast from `ITwo` to `Mock<ITwo>`? I hope it's clear :)

Thank you.

edit:

I hope this exampler is clearer:

```
interface IHuman
{
    void Sneeze();
    INose Nose { get; set;}
}

interface INose
{
    event EventHandler Irritated;
}

class ToBeTested
{
    private IHuman _human;

    public ToBeTested(IHuman human)
    {
        _human = human;

        _human.Nose.Irritated += NoseIrritated;
    }

    void NoseIrritated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _human.Sneeze();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access Mock from Mock. So I can do somethiong like:

```
noseMock.Raise(nose => nose.Irritated += null);
humanMock.Verify(human => human.Sneeze());
```

Comment: The question is specific to Moq. I know you can't fire events from interfaces directly, that's why I need Moq :). Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for the edit, be aware that a fifth (or sixth?) edit makes your issue a Community Wiki question, so be careful (welcome at SO, this is one of the lesser known "features"). See, among othersL http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47902/can-we-make-an-edit-not-move-a-question-up-instead-of-making-it-community-wiki-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not *entirely* sure what you're asking for, but it looks like you're trying to work out how to get from a mocked object to the `Mock<T>` wrapper that produced it? ("how can I cast from `ITwo` to `Mock<ITwo>`?")

It's pretty easy: there's a `Mock.Get` method that finds the `Mock<T>` for a T (as long as that object came from Moq).

```
Mock<ITwo> mockTwo = Mock.Get(two);
```

Details can be found in the Moq Getting started guide:

http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Advanced_Features

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. That's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the interfaces itself you cannot raise events, as interfaces cannot contain code, only contracts. If you want to communicate between objects that implement IOne and ITwo, the best way is, indeed, to add an event sink and register to that event from either of the implementations.

But: you cannot do this automagically through interfaces alone.

### Edit

You meanwhile edited your question. What is `Mock<T>` for you? You cannot cast from `ITwo` to `Mock<T>`. The reverse might be possible if `Mock<T>` inherits from `ITwo`.

*Note: Perhaps an example with words other than One and Two might help us understand what you really after?*

### Code example

Answering just *"How can I raise an event on ITwo when I only have a reference to IOne or Mock"*, hopefully I understand a bit what you're after:

```
interface IOne 
{
    void RaiseEventITwo();
    ITwo Two { get; set;}   
}

// note: left out some details
class One : IOne
{
    public One() { this.Two = new Two(); }    // Two implements ITwo
    public void RaiseEventITwo()
    {
        this.Two.OnLoadPage();   // i.e.: some event of ITwo is OnLoadPage
    }
}

// somewhere where you actually have the reference you speak off
IOne one = new One();   // class One implements IOne
one.RaiseEventITwo();

// using the Mock<T> class:
Mock<IOne> mockOne = new Mock<IOne>();
mockOne.GetIOne().RaiseEventITwo();      // GetIOne needs to be implemented in 
                                         // Mock<T> or as extension for Mock<T>
```